# How to write out multiple files to the environment after apply a function?

Tags: r, matrix

I would like to transform 96 .txt files to matrix in R with `data.matirx`

Here is part of input data in one files

```
   Domain  Phylum   Class   Order 
OTU10001   Fungi   Ascomycota   Dothideomycetes   Capnodiales   
OTU10004   Fungi   Ascomycota   Dothideomycetes   Pleosporales
```

And the code for single files:

```
BC76_OTU <- data.matrix(BC76.frequencytable)
```

I am trying to process all the files with data.matirx and write out each file to the environment with the following code:

```
Feature_to_matrix <- function(x) {
  x <- as.matrix (files)
  return(x)
}

files <- list.files(path="path to directory", pattern="*.txt", full.names=TRUE, recursive=FALSE)
lapply(files, function(Feature_to_matrix) {
  t <- read.table(Feature_to_matrix, header=TRUE, row.names=1, sep="") 
  out <- t
})
```

But this code doesn't generate output files to the R environment. 
Any suggestions?
Thanks!

I also try to write a loop for it

```
        temp = list.files(pattern="*.txt"

for (i in 1:length(temp)) { 
sample[i] <- read.csv(temp[i], header = TRUE,row.names=1,sep = "") write.matrix(sample[i]) }
```

but get an error as follow

```
Error in sample[i] <- read.csv(temp[i], header = TRUE, row.names = 1, : object of type 'closure' is not subsettable
```

could anyone give me some suggestion to modify the code?

Comment: Do you get any errors when running the code?

Comment: Nope, I didn't get any errors. It just didn't generate output files to the environment...

Comment: 1) `x` is the argument to function `Feature_to_matrix` but then you use `as.matrix(files)` when it probably should be `as.matrix(x)`. 2) `lapply(files, function(Feature_to_matrix)` doesn't make sense, use `df_list <- lapply(files, function(fl) read.table(fl, etc))`. No need to assign to an extra variable `t`. 3) After reading in the files like I say in point 2), `mat_list <- lapply(df_list, Feature_to_matrix)`.

Comment: I tried mat_list <- lapply(df_list, Feature_to_matrix). It gave a list output in the environment. I think I can further try to split the list to separated files

Comment: For 96 files, why not just a simple for-loop? It is possible to go overboard in trying to vectorize everything in R (something which `lapply` doesn't really do anyway).

Comment: I also want to try that, but I am not familiar with writing a loop. Could you give me a quick example of that?